# Tool to detect plagiarism within my source code, by searching github/gitlab/bitbucket/etc

Tags: c#, github, plagiarism-detection, bitbucket

I have C# project i want to check did my developed used any file/code from other repository which have license terms . I need to extract that piece of code and License . do you have software or script available ?

I need Script which pick each of my file and would check block of code . it could be 3 line or 5 line and would search from github/gitlab/bitbucket etc and if it's able to find the code then extract license from that repository and provide me data in csv or some other format

Comment: yes I need to check like my developed has copied code from other repo which have some license terms